# Play application | How to pass FilePart to other request

Tags: java, playframework

in java play application i exposed Put request of file and i want use this FilePart in another request by wsClient:

```
public CompletionStage<String> upload() {
        Http.RequestBody body = request().body();
        Http.MultipartFormData formData = body.asMultipartFormData();
        Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<File> file = formData.getFile("file");

        return wsClient.url("fake")
                .setContentType("multipart/form-data")
                .post(Source.single(b))
                .thenApplyAsync(wsResponse -> {
                        return wsResponse.getBody();
                })
                .exceptionally(throwable -> throwable.getMessage());
    }
```

And i got as response: 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Part Class'

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

This post endpoint will require a body of the type:

```
Source<? super Http.MultipartFormData.Part<Source<ByteString, ?>>, ?>
```

Which can be constructed from a list of form parts in the following manner:

```
List<Http.MultipartFormData.Part> partList = new ArrayList<>();
Source<ByteString, ?> file = FileIO.fromFile(filePart.getFile());
Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<Source<ByteString, ?>> filePart = new Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart<>(file.getKey(), file.getFilename(), filePart.getContentType(), file);
partList.add(filePart);
```

You can then provide this as a body to the post using the following:

```
.post(Source.from(Collections.unmodifiableList(partList)))
```